# What does the Power Save option do on 3DS consoles?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

If I go in to the brightness control on my 3DSXL, I see that there is a "Power-Saving Mode" that can be turned on or off. Presumably this reduces the power consumption of 3DS consoles, but how does it achieve it and how much of a boost in battery life does it yield?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They talked about the Power Save mode of the first 3DS during an "Iwata Asks" session:

> Employing a technology called "active backlight," this feature "precisely controls the brightness of the backlight according to the brightness of the screen being displayed," Umezu explained. "When the screen as a whole is dark, the backlight itself gets darker, which saves power."

And about the battery-time you would save:

> The energy savings offered by the power save mode should make it a requisite for every 3DS player. "With the backlight set to the brightest level and the power save mode turned off, battery duration was about three hours," Umezu said. "But if you use the power save mode under the same conditions, it gets about **10–20 percent longer**."

(From [Joystiq](http://www.joystiq.com/2011/01/28/nintendo-3ds-power-save-mode-illuminated/))

Comment: How much does it alter the look of the colours and thus of the whole game? When I tried it out, even in the system menu the difference was recognizable.

Comment: I don't think you can get numbers for that, but yes, you can notice the difference right away: light colors get more pale (white becomes yellowish) and the contrast is lower. It's like playing with the first DS.